# What does "Trying to get the most beads" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The daughter has very low grades at university and her father reprimands her, the conversation goes like this:

> What are you doing down there in Louisiana anyway? Trying to get the most beads?

> Gross. No, dad.

What does "Trying to get the most beads" mean?

Comment: I can answer this one without more context.  But please come back and edit to add the **source** of this quote.  I guess it is from American TV program, but which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "tradition" at the Mardi Gras celebrations in Louisiana.  Women expose their breasts in exchange for bead necklaces  (The people who organise Marde Gras in New Orleans [try to discourage it](https://www.mardigrasneworleans.com/history/traditions/flashing)).  See also [this comic](https://xkcd.com/996/), in which a woman plays the same game with her doctor.

So dad is asking "Why were you in Lousiana? Were you showing your breasts to strangers at the Mardi Gras?"  And, of course, being asked sexual questions by your father is "gross".